# How to pass post array parameter in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I was just wondering how to pass in post parameters such as following exercept from html options, normally i would get a array in language such as php (`POST['param'][0]...` would work i believe)

```
url?param=value1&param=value2&param=value3
```

I tried:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void action(String[] param)
```

But this doesn't work for some reason...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you want to add @RequestParam to your method param

Comment: Does any of the proposed solutions work?

Comment: Hi, even I am facing the same problem now. So it is better to use -> (@RequestParam(value = "param[]") String[] paramValues) "OR" (@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params) . I am confused. Can you please help me?

Comment: I think best syntax is param[]=value1&param[]=value2&... because multiple simple (without special postfix like "[]") params may be considered as program error. Can Spring MVC parse this into array?

Answer (score 55):

You can use this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void action(@RequestParam(value = "param[]") String[] paramValues){...}
```

it will retrieve all values (inside array `paramValues`) of parameter `param` (note the attribute `value` of `RequestParam`: it ends with `[]`)

Comment: By the way, when you send ajax param in jquery, don't forget to make the array param name also end with "[]".

Comment: Does this work with an integer or long array?  So far, I can only make this work with strings.

Comment: @kaleemsagard Hi, even I am facing the same problem now. So it is better to use -> (@RequestParam(value = "param[]") String[] paramValues) "OR" (@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params) . I am confused. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Chandz I think that `@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params` retrieves all the parameters in the request, not only the values of the parameter `param` that are needed, so you can use the `MultiValueMap` object and search in it all the ocurrences of the parameter `param`. That could take harder work than `@RequestParam(value = "param[]")`.

Comment: The only right solution that I have found on the internet. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void action(@RequestParam("param") String[] param)
```

Comment: This does work but is slightly different from what the question asks - this will map a SINGLE parameter that has an array as a value; however MULTIPLE parameters (presumably with dynamic and hard to anticipate names) cannot be mapped like this.

Comment: @Eugen: Hi, even I am facing the same problem now. So it is better to use -> _(@RequestParam(value = "param[]") String[] paramValues)_ "OR" _(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params)_ . I am confused. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is still struggling with that, this is how it should be done:

Form inputs:

```
<input name="myParam" value="1"/>
<input name="myParam" value="4"/>
<input name="myParam" value="19"/>
```

Controller method:

```
   @RequestMapping
    public String deletePlaces(@RequestParam("myParam") Long[] myParams) {

      //myParams will have 3 elements with values 1,4 and 19
    }
```

This works the same for `String[]` `Integer[]` `Long[]` and probably more. `POST`,`GET`,`DELETE` will work the same way.

Parameter name must match `name` tag from form input. No extra `[]` needed etc. In fact, param name can be ommited, if method argument name is the same as input name so we can end up with method signature like this:

```
   @RequestMapping
   public String deletePlaces(@RequestParam Long[] myParams)
```

and it will still work

**Something extra:**
Now if you have domain model lets say `Place` and you have `PlaceRepository`, by providing `Place#id` as value of your inputs, Spring can lookup related objects for us. So if we assume that form inputs above contais User ids as values, then we can simply write this into controller:

```
public String deletePlaces(@RequestParam Place[] places) {
  //places will be populated with related entries from database!
 }
```

Sweet isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

If you know your param name, try

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void action(@RequestParam("myParam") String param)
```

Another way is to use the current request object:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void action(HttpServletRequest request) {
Map parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
...

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void action(@RequestParam(value = "param[]") String[] paramValues {...}
```

This will work when you send for example ajax by jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { param:paramValues }
    ...
});
```

but when you send only single element array with String, which contains commas like "foo,baa", Spring will split this String and create array with 2 elements "foo" and "baa".
So be careful with commas when your array can have also one element.

Answer (score 0):

1, add a java class as requestBody

```
public class PostMembers {
    private String[] members;

    public String[] getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(String[] members) {
        this.members = members;
    }
}
```

2, add a method in controller class

```
@PostMapping("")
public List<SomeClass> addMember(@RequestBody PostMembers postMembers) {
// ...
}
```

now your controller can get array params .

3, test with curl

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json"  \
 -X POST -d '{"members":["item1","item2"]}' \
 http://localhost:8080/api/xxx
```

or if you use vue

```
axios.post(someUrl,{
    members:[
       'item1','item2'
    ]
}).then(response =>{
// ...
})
```