# How to receive dynamically generated input value in spring as bean

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

In my project i dynamically generate the text box in table like below

```
project Name Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4 Date5 Activity 
java                                        Development Addnew
C++                                         Development Addnew
```

i display tables for one week.if user clicks addnew i generate the dynamic text box below the row where user clicked addnew button.

My problem is how to get all the textbox value in my spring controller as bean class.Because i am not sure abut how many text boxes are come in page load and submit.

Any Idea will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What does your current spring controller look like? Also what front end stack (if any) are you using, jQuery, angular etc?

Comment: my front end stack is jquery.i am confused how to receive this request in controller

Comment: Is there one big submit button on the form, or are you expecting the backend to add a row in whatever database when the user presses 'Add new'

Comment: submit an array and use a list in your spring controller, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399347/how-to-pass-post-array-parameter-in-spring-mvc for example

Comment: @Adam,if user perform one or more activity in a project per week he click add new for log time for each activity.i generate that textbox in jquery not bd level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't enough specifics in your question for a specific answer. However the general approach I would recommend.

- If you have a framework like Backbone or Angular, investigate use of its collection facilities.
- Write JavaScript that builds JSON array from all your textfields
- Define a POJO in Java that mirrors each entry in your array.
- Ensure you're using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) - this maps JSON to Java objects for you before your controller is called
- Define an method in your controller that takes a list of POJO, e.g. create(List values) with a URL like /times/{ employeeId} using PUT
- For reading out of the database, add method in your controller that returns a list of POJO, e.g. List values get(long employeeId) with a URL like /times/{ employeeId} using GET
- Alternatively if you need the form to be 'live', i.e. 'Add new' causes row in database instantly use a REST interface with a create, update and DELETE using POST, PUT and DELETE respectively

I assume you'll need to update the list later, so I'd recommend a structure with an ID which can be used for CREATE and UPDATE operations, not just a plain list of Strings, this will also allow more fields later.

```
public void Foo {
  private String project;
  private String name;
  private long id;
  // getters + setters
}
```

JSON for a create

```
[{"project":"java","name":"Development",id:0}, {"project":"C++","name":"Development",id:0}]
```

JSON for a later update, i.e. with IDs round-tripped

```
[{"project":"java","name":"Development",id:100}, {"project":"C++","name":"Development",id:101}]
```

Comment: ,as per my requirement single project contains more activity for example project:java activity:design project:java activity:development.so how to identify this criteria in controller

Answer (score 2):

Go with the traditional `getParameter()` method. I assume your text box will have unique names while generated using `jquery`.

In the controller,

```
   List<String> requestParameterNames = Collections.list((Enumeration<String>) request.getParameterNames());

for (String parameterName : requestParameterNames) {
    String attributeName = parameterName;
    String attributeValue = request.getParameter(parameterName);
    // will have the text box values 

}
```

Comment: i generate the text box using jstl in load time and generate text box dynamically when user clicks add new.how i associate this name is this project because as per my requirement one project may take two or more rows