# Spring: Insert multiple invoice rows into database with invoiceId as Foreign Key

Tags: javascript, mysql, spring

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="description[0]"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[0]" id="quantity[0]" onkeyup="sum(0);" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[0]" id="price[0]" onkeyup="sum(0);"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lineTotal[0]" id="lineTotal[0]" readonly /></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="addLine();" value="+" /></td>
</tr>
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var i = 0;
    function addLine() {
            i++;        
            var row = document.createElement('tr');
            var td = document.createElement('td');
             td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="description['+i+']" id="description['+i+']"/>';
                row.appendChild(td);
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="quantity['+i+']" id="quantity['+i+']" onkeyup="sum('+i+');"/>';
                row.appendChild(td);
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="price['+i+']" id="price['+i+']" onkeyup="sum('+i+');"/>';
                row.appendChild(td);
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="lineTotal['+i+']" id="lineTotal['+i+']" readonly/>';
                row.appendChild(td);
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = '<input type="button" onclick="removeLine(this.parentNode.parentNode)" value="-">';
                row.appendChild(td);
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = '<input type="button" onclick="addLine();" value="+" />';
                row.appendChild(td);

                document.getElementById('items').appendChild(row);
            }

            function removeLine(row) {
              document.getElementById('items').removeChild(row);
            }


        function sum(i) {
            var q = document.getElementById('quantity['+i+']').value;
            var p = document.getElementById('price['+i+']').value;
            var result = parseFloat(q) * parseFloat(p);

            if(q=="" || p==""){
                document.getElementById('lineTotal['+i+']').value = 0;
            }

            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('lineTotal['+i+']').value = result.toFixed(2);
            } 
        }
```

.

```
public static void invoiceDescription(
            long invoiceId, String description, int quantity, 
            int price, int lineTotal){

            Connection dbConnection = null;
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

            String sql = "INSERT INTO invoice_description"
                    + "(descId, invoiceId, description, quantity, price, total) VALUES"
                    + "(NULL,?,?,?,?,?)";

            try {

                dbConnection = getDBConnection();

                preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());


                preparedStatement.setLong(1, invoiceId);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, description);
                preparedStatement.setInt(3, quantity);
                preparedStatement.setInt(4, price);
                preparedStatement.setInt(5, lineTotal);

                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("You have successfully added descriptions to invoice");


            } catch (SQLException e){

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            }
    }
```

Above is my html, javascript and database manager for inserting data into the database. As i am able to add new rows to the html through javascript, i cannot however enter the multiple data into the database.

My controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/invoice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitInvoice(HttpServletRequest request, 
            @RequestParam("clients") int clientId,
            @RequestParam("invoice_date") String invoice_date, 
            @RequestParam("invoice_due_date") String invoice_due_date, 
            @RequestParam("status") String status, 
            @RequestParam("payment_method") String payment_method, 
            @RequestParam("currency") String currency, 
            @RequestParam("description") String description,        @RequestParam("quantity") int quantity, @RequestParam("price") int price, @RequestParam("lineTotal") String lineTotal, 
) {

        if(!hasRole(request, "ROLE_USER")){
            return "403";
        }


         long invoiceId = DBManager.createInvoice(clientId, invoice_date, invoice_due_date, status, payment_method, currency);
        DBManager.invoiceDescription(invoiceId, description, quantity, price, lineTotal);

        return "redirect:/invoice/detail/" + invoiceId;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share both the SQL output from javascript and the error you are getting?

Comment: i don't have any sql output from javascript. all what javascript is doing is adding rows dynamically and and calculating the rows. the problem is inserting those rows into the database. The error i get is "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." when i am submitting. I am pretty sure it has to do with the "[]" in the dynamic names on the html which is rejecting it. but i am not able to solve it

Comment: What I meant was: could you do a console.log(preparedStatement) and let us know what the output is?

Comment: thats the result i am getting still "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Comment: i removed the [0] from the names in the html, and i was able to add the data into the database. but when i add the [0] to dynamically add and calculate the row in the table then it doesnt add. I hope you're getting what i am saying. i don't see it as a major error, the only thing is that i am not able to solve and its been like that for days.. I need to dynamically add data into the database into multiple rows.

Comment: When you have index in your form parameters for example quantity[0] it means that you are sending array of objects, but in your RequestParam you try to map this array to simple object. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399347/how-to-pass-post-array-parameter-in-spring-mvc 
But if you want to make it properly you should probably use spring form tags and ModelAttribute instead of RequestParams

Comment: @jgr I've tried the way it is on the link you send but i get an error when i have to do "preparedStatement.getString" and ".getInt". It won't compile. thats with requestparams.

Comment: i figured out that recursive arrays should be used in my code! any idea on how to format my database class into arrays for multiple entry. please help :)