# Required request parameter for method parameter type String[] is not present spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to read an array value from query param which is passes as

```
ot-replace[0]=kin43
```

On the controller I have

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{userId}/**")
public ResponseEntity<String> viewObject(@PathVariable(value = "userId") String uid, 
@RequestParam(name="ot-replace")String[] regexReplace){}
```

I get the following error

```
 "trace": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'ot-replace' for method parameter type String[] is not present\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValueInternal(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:193)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.
```

Comment: Show full method, show GET/POST? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399347/how-to-pass-post-array-parameter-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of ot-replace[0]=kin43  replace with ot-replace=kin43&ot-replace=kin44
You will get two item in your array.